# What neutral planets existed at the time of the Rebellion?

Tags: star-wars, planets

During the establishment of the Empire and the rise of the Rebellion, were there any important (populous, wealthy, and/or strategic) planets which were neutral, meaning not nominally part of the Empire?  For example, any planets not formally part of the Old Republic would therefore not automatically been part of the Empire, though presumably some were conquered.

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hutt_Space), even Hutt Space was annexed by the Empire.

As described in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9525/how-many-planets-were-there-in-the-empire-at-the-time-of-a-new-hope?rq=1), there are LOTS of worlds in the Star Wars galaxy, and only a fraction were part of the Republic or the Empire.  Did any Core worlds exist outside the Empire or was the heart of their space incontestably theirs? What was the closest non-Empire aligned world to Empire space?

Comment: As asked, this is a straight list question. I'm going to edit it so it's not, feel free to roll it back if I don't capture what you are actually asking, but you will probably still have to edit it to keep it open.

Comment: I was gonna say Tatooine, but the question was edited to "closest" :)

Comment: You could search the lists of planets found [here](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=list+of+star+wars+planets+by+political+affiliatioin). I would, but I gotta go

Comment: Where's Google Maps when you need it

Comment: Several *regions* were neutral:

[Chiss Ascendency](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chiss_Ascendancy);
[Empire of the Hand](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Empire_of_the_Hand) (quasi-neutral);
[Hapes Cluster](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hapes_Cluster);
[Vagaari Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vagaari_Empire) (weak).
There were, of course several sectors that the Empire maintained only a token presence in that never joined the Rebellion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few neutral planets of note are **Adari** (signed a non-aggression treaty with the Empire during the Galactic Civil War. In exchange for Adarian neutrality, the planet supplied large amounts of raw materials to the Empire), **Aridus** (Home of the Chubbits and have always been neutral in Galactic affairs, avoiding the Clone Wars and the rise of the Empire. However, with many valuable resources under the planet's surface, it could not avoid attention forever. When the Empire discovered the seemingly-endless amount of resources, Imperial mining teams rushed to exploit them and this wreaked havoc on the native Chubbits, who, with the assistance of the Rebel Alliance, forced the Empire to leave), **Arkania Prime** (Many of the crystals used for making lightsabers are found deep underground on Arkania Prime, although the people of the planet do not want to risk going deep underground), and **Bimmisaari**. Hope this helps!